# Python Selemium- Cannot click on button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hope you´re fine,
Please! Hope you can support me with this topic.
I tried lot of ways to try to click this button by Selenium but I couldn´t. The error is that Selenium cannot locate the object.

```
ERROR MESSAAGE: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath", "selector":"//*[@id='C47_W166_V167_thtmlb_button_2']"}
```

Here The python code to make click:

```
window_before = driver.window_handles[0] #Save Current window 
window_after = driver.window_handles[1] #Identify new raised window  
driver.switch_to.window(window_after) #To go to new raised window 

time.sleep(3)

driver.maximize_window()

driver.switch_to.frame("WorkAreaFrame1popup")
print(driver.title)
time.sleep(3)

ALL_BRANDS_BTN= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='C51_W184_V185_thtmlb_button_2']")
ALL_BRANDS_BTN.click()
```

I made the same for other buttons on the same web tool without any issues, but for this particular button I can´t. Maybe I´m missing something?
I already put extra waiting time but neither worked.

Im attaching an image of the element inspection. Please, hope you can help me,
Thanks in advance

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="th-bt th-bt-text" onclick="thBtMgr.click(this);return htmlbSL(this,2,'C51_W184_V185_thtmlb_button_2:EXCEL','0')" onmousedown="thBtMgr.press(this,event);" onfocusout="thBtMgr.unpress(this);" onfocus="thSaveKbFocus(this);" oncontextmenu="return false;" ondragstart="return false;" id="C51_W184_V185_thtmlb_button_2"><span class="th-bt-span"><b class="th-bt-b">All Brands</b></span></a>

<span class="th-bt-span"><b class="th-bt-b">All Brands</b></span>
```

Comment: Could you provide us with a link to the web-page?

Comment: Sir, I would like but is SAP CRM, VPN is needed to do it. In wich other way I can post the issue?

Comment: In the html you posted, you have `id="C51_W184_V185_thtmlb_button_2"` but you are searching for a different id in your xpath.

Comment: Sorry I updated my comment with Python code I used. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned you have used same kind of code for other buttons So I am assuming you are in correct window and iFrame. If not please insure your button is in correct windoe and frame.

Can you try below code to click your button:

```
btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//b[text()='All Brands']//ancestor::a"))) #Used Text instea of Id , as not sure if ID is dynamic or not
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", btn ) #Scroll to button
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn ) #Click then button
```